# How to add X11 desktop environment in yocto configuration?

Tags: x11, yocto

I  tried to build the BSP for v3msk (linux based embedded system) on Ubuntu 18.04 following the link:

https://elinux.org/R-Car/Boards/Yocto-Gen3-ADAS#Building_the_BSP_for_Renesas_ADAS_boards

I used Yocto v3.21.0

The local.conf I used is available here https://pastebin.com/UyBGzQ2J

I tried adding x11 to distro features.

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " x11"
```

I ran

```
bitbake core-image-x11
```

and I expect it to build yocto images with X11.

I got error :

```
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'core-image-x11'
core-image-x11 was skipped: missing required distro feature 'x11' (not in 
DISTRO_FEATURES)
```

What could be missing in local.conf?

Comment: where is recipe for `core-image-x11` coming from? you probably wanna build `core-image-minimal`.

Comment: ok, I build with core-image-minimal . the build is successful. but I don't see Xorg or x11 in the rootfs. I added `x11` and `x11-base` to `DISTRO_FEATURES_append` in local.conf

Comment: Thats because adding something to `DISTRO_FEATURES` does not install it. You have to enable the distro feature `x11`, then you should be able to build `core-image-x11`. Yet, please note that this only holds true if the hardwarew supports it and the setup is correct. The wiki page you mentioned is rather referring to `core-image-weston`, so that might be a better start.

Answer (score 0):

**Nothing PROVIDES 'core-image-x11'**

means you don't have image file with this name in the meta layers list of your **build/conf/bblayers.conf** file.

try to execute command:

```
find source| grep images| grep x11
```

to see if you have any layer containing images related to x11. add discovered layer to the **build/conf/bblayers.conf** file then retry your command:

```
bitbake core-image-x11
```